# Need to initialize @State var in constructor, but @FetchRequest hasn't returned yet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two core data classes that conform to a protocol `GalleryItem`.
First I get load data with `FetchRequest`:

```swift
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CloudPage.orderIndex, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var pages: FetchedResults<CloudPage>

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Folder.orderIndex, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var folders: FetchedResults<Folder>

    // I also have this items array
    @State var items:[GalleryItem]
```

Here I'm trying to initialize `items` in `init`:

```swift
    init() {
        self.items = getOrderedItems()
    }
```

And here's `getOrderedItems()`:

```
func getOrderedItems(in folder:Folder?) -> [GalleryItem] {
        let pages = getAllPages()
        let folders = getAllFolders()
        return (pages + folders).sorted {
            $0.getOrderIndex() < $1.getOrderIndex()
        }
    }
```

The trouble is, the `pages` and `folders` arrays are empty when this runs. Those functions have pretty simple implementations:

```swift
func getAllPages() -> [CloudPage] {
        var arr:[CloudPage] = []
        for p in pages {
            arr.append(p)
        }
        return arr
    }
    
    func getAllFolders() -> [Folder] {
        var arr:[Folder] = []
        for p in folders {
            arr.append(p)
        }
        return arr
    }
```

I'm guessing the code inside init is running before the request finishes? How can I wait for the request to finish so `items` doesn't end up empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
    @State var items:[GalleryItem]

    init() {
        self.items = getOrderedItems()
    }
```

usual pattern is to do this in `onAppear`, like

```
    @State var items:[GalleryItem] = []

    var body: some View {
        Text("Your root view here")
          .onAppear {
             self.items = getOrderedItems()      // << here !!
          }
    }
```

Comment: That isn't just gambling on when the fetch request will have completed?